# Parsing table data to $_POST in php

Tags: php, html, html-table, http-post

I have try to fix this simple web pages.

I make a table from this file :

`*$SY100                $L01$F001$T001$B00000010$I001$G00101$R00000000$O01$NPATCH KABEL ORA 2M  $
*$SY101                $L01$F001$T001$B00000018$I001$G00101$R00000000$O01$NLASTBARARE SVART    $
*$SY102                $L01$F001$T003$B00000012$I001$G00101$R00000000$O01$NPATH KABEL GRA 1M   $
*$SY103                $L01$F001$T004$B00000006$I001$G00101$R00000000$O01$NATERSTALL KNAPP     $`

and want to use a text field to get a "quantity"  how how do I get it this rows in the post command?

```
<?php
echo "<form action='' method='post'>";
echo "<table>
<tr>
<th scope='col' >Art No</th>
<th scope='col' >Avalible Quantity</th>
<th scope='col' >Quantity</th>
</tr>";
$file1 = "/srv/ftp/inBox/amdbackup.amd";
$lines = file($file1);

foreach($lines as $line_num => $line){
    $rows = explode("\$",$line);
    $article_no = substr ($rows['1'],1);
    $avalible_quantity = ltrim (substr ($rows['5'],1),0);

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $article_no . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $avalible_quantity . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<input size='2' type='text'></input>" . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }

echo "</table>";
echo "<input name='add' type='submit'><br>";
echo "</form>";

if (IsSet($_POST['add'])) {
$art_no=$_POST['id'];
$quantity=$_POST['q'];

echo "art_no" . $art_no;
echo "</br>";
echo "quantity" . $quantity;
echo "</br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, i think my previous answer was incorrect. Also, I don't see any fields named `id` or `q` in your `form`.

You might want to replace

```
<input size='2' type='text'></input>
```

with

```
<input size='2' type='text' name='q' />
```

Though you will have to add another field for `id`

Comment: I just checked and it doesn't seem to matter, PHP will accept both key indexes. I deleted my comment above which offered the same suggestion.

Comment: @CodyCaughlan: Oh thanks.. I thought that might be the issue in addition to the my edited answer

Comment: Yes i have tried that but i did't understand how i get the connection between article no and quantity ?